# ¿Cómo conectar dos archivos .cpp, de forma que pueda pasar la informacion de una estructura a otro documento?

Tags: c++, estructuras-de-datos

```
//main.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include "stats.hpp"

using namespace std;

typedef struct pokemon{
    int vida,defensa,defensa_especial,ataque,ataque_especial,velocidad;
}pikachu,charmander,bulbasaur,squirtle,player,enemy;

void stats(); //Prototipo

int main(){
    
    stats(); //Entro a la función
    
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

```
//stats.hpp
#include <iostream>
#include <main.cpp>

void stats(){
    //Pikachu
    pikachu.ataque=5;
    pikachu.ataque_especial=20;
    pikachu.defensa=10;
    pikachu.defensa_especial=5;
    pikachu.velocidad=2;
    pikachu.vida=40;
}
```

> En resumen, mi problema viene que los stars de los pokemons no están declarados, por lo que necesito saber cómo declararlos si la estructura se encuentra en el main.cpp

> En el void stats, aunque en la imagen aparezcan todos los pokemons no declarados, lo he acortado para que no haya tanta info innecesaria.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Cl7F.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/xWjgQ.png

Comment: Crea un archivo `stats.hpp` y pon todas las declaraciones alli. Luego incluye ese archivo en tu main.

Comment: @Pablochaches no funciona, me salta el error de: 
`
[Error] stats.hpp: No such file or directory ||
compilation terminated ||
.recipe for target 'main.o' failed
` ||
Es raro, cuando intercambio los '<>' por las comillas dobles, me da el mismo error que la imagen adjuntada con el problema, si no me da lo que he comentado.

Comment: Vale, he intentado incluir en la libreria de "stats.hpp" el "main.cpp" así: ||#include "main.cpp"|| y entró en un bucle raro donde tuve que forzar el cierre del compilador, si es posible hay alguna forma de incluir uno a otro y viceversa sin que colapse?

Comment: No tienes que incluirlos mutuamente. Crea `stats.hpp` con las declaraciones, y en `main.cpp` haces: `#include "stats.hpp"`. Luego compilas incluyendo `main.cpp` y `stats.cpp`.

Comment: Nop, no funciona, y vuelvo al problema original. debe de haber alguna forma de incluir la estructura que se encuentra en main.cpp a stats.hpp para que los declare, ya que para stats.hpp, "pikachu.x" no existe.

Comment: Puedes editar tu pregunta mostrando los archivos?

Comment: @Pablochaches listo. No sé qué ocurtrrio con las imagenes, perdona que de repente se hayan eliminado.  https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Cl7F.png era esto lo que pedías?

Comment: No incluyas el main en `stats.hpp`. Las declaraciones (esto incluye la de la estructura), tienes que moverlas a `stats.hpp`.

Comment: Okey, gracias!!

Answer (score 0):

```
//main.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include "stats.hpp"

using namespace std;

void stats();

int main(){
    
    stats();
    
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

```
//stats.hpp
#include <iostream>

struct pokemon{
    int vida,defensa,defensa_especial,ataque,ataque_especial,velocidad;
}pikachu,charmander,bulbasaur,squirtle,player,enemy;


void stats(){
    //Pikachu
    pikachu.ataque=5;
    pikachu.ataque_especial=20;
    pikachu.defensa=10;
    pikachu.defensa_especial=5;
    pikachu.velocidad=2;
    pikachu.vida=40;
    
    //Charmander
    charmander.ataque=4;
    charmander.ataque_especial=30;
    charmander.defensa=9;
    charmander.defensa_especial=10;
    charmander.velocidad=1;
    charmander.vida=35;
    
    //Bulbasaur
    bulbasaur.ataque=8;
    bulbasaur.ataque_especial=15;
    bulbasaur.defensa=10;
    bulbasaur.defensa_especial=15;
    bulbasaur.velocidad=2;
    bulbasaur.vida=50;
    
    //Squirtle
    squirtle.ataque=10;
    squirtle.ataque_especial=20;
    squirtle.defensa=15;
    squirtle.defensa_especial=5;
    squirtle.velocidad=1;
    squirtle.vida=40;
}
```

Comment: Considera leer [answer], editar y aportar una explicación de tu código por favor